# Angular how to provide more than one error handler

Tags: angular

In my Angular application I need to use 2 Error handler, 1 is my custom error handler and 1 is the [Elastic error handler](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/angular-integration.html).
So is it possible to use both?

At the moment I see that the last one I register in app.module overwrite the previous one, and it is not possible to use `multi: true` like the interceptor.

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: CustomErrorHandler
    },
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: ApmErrorHandler
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, hope this works

```
export class ApmErrorHandler extends CustomErrorHandler
{
   handleError(error: any)
   {
       super.handleError(error);
   }
}

providers: [
  {
     provide: ErrorHandler,
     useClass: ApmErrorHandler 
  }
]
```